# Arduino One communication through nrf24 module using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arduino, arduino-uno

I was wondering if it can be possible to write a program over a Arduino One board (through serial port) using nodeJS that use nrf24 communication for talking to other boards. Unfortunately I'm not that skilled with C language neither expert with Arduino and I would prefer to use nodeJs for writing my program.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can only send code to an Arduino via the Arduino IDE. The Ardino IDE only understands and compiles C++, so no, you can't write an Arduino program with nodeJS.

There is an Arduino alternative called Tessel, which does run node.js code:  https://tessel.io/

Comment: Why can't I write an Arduino program with NodeJS? Using the package Jhonny-five I've been able to light a led or read button push for example.

Comment: On the documentation says "The JavaScript program is executed on a host machine that runs Node.js." So the arduino isn't running the code really. If you want the arduino to run the code you'll have to write with C. If you want a microcontroller that runs nodeJS natively use the Tessel, as suggested by Johnny-Five.